# Keras - specify output shape of LSTM layer

Tags: python, keras, lstm, dimension

I have sequential model in Keras where input and output data have shape (10000, 10, 300) each:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(10,300), units=300, return_sequences=False, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", recurrent_initializer="glorot_normal"))
model.add(LSTM(return_sequences=True, units=300, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="glorot_normal", recurrent_initializer="glorot_normal"))
model.compile(loss="cosine_proximity", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I want first layer to return only last output (result of every cell in layer together (if I understand correctly) because I need context of whole sequence) and feed it as input to second layer (that's why I use `return_sequences=False` in first layer). Second layer should take it and output full sequence of shape (10,300).

I recieve this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

How can I specify correct output shape of the first layer for the second layer to accept it?
Or should I do it all differently?

If you need any further informations I will provide them.

Thank you for any reply

Comment: With `return_sequences=False`, the first LSTM layer provides an output of shape (batch_size, 300). However, the second LSTM layer is expecting an input of dimensionality 3, namely (batch_size, n_timesteps, 300). To stack multiple LSTMs, the argument `return_sequences` is usually set to `True`, but in you case you might want to pad the input of the first LSTM with zeros, so that it has shape (batch_size, n_timesteps, 300). A LSTM with with n_timesteps=1 wouldn't make sense.